# Flex AIR: How to define proxy without Blaze DS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have an AIR app that I need to define a proxy for because the services sit behind a firewall.

We are not using BlazeDS so I can't define the proxy settings in the proxy-config.xml file. So, how do I do it?

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I'm having a hard time with this issue.

I'm guessing that I'm not the first person who has had to work behind a firewall when accessing data so I'm not sure why I can't find any documentation on the web anywhere about this.

AIR says it is supposed to automatically know and use the proxy configuration from your system, i.e. default browser. In there, I don't set a manual proxy, I use the 'automatic configuration' and point it to a .dat file. Could this be where the problem is? Does AIR not know how to understand this?

There's no way to set a proxy on an HTTPService component unless you are using Blaze DS or LCDS? Is this true? I'd hate to have to add that to my application just so I can get this accomplished.

Comment: You should be able to easily create a proxy in any server side language of your choice, but I'm not sure I understand. You need to define a proxy on the client?  Or on a server?  If the AIR client can't access the server side services; how would installing a proxy on the client help?  If the AIR Client can't access the server side services; how would installing a server side proxy help?

Comment: I need to connect to services within a corp firewall. So I must go thru a proxy.

Comment: This could be my ignorance of enterprise class network setups, but why?  Are you looking to create a proxy or use an existing proxy?  How do you expect the proxy will solve the issue of routing around the firewall? If you're AIR Client doesn't have access, why would the Proxy?

Comment: I'm looking to use an existing proxy; sorry, I should have said that.

Comment: Basically, I need to figure out how to go thru an external proxy for HTTPService requests.

Comment: Won't an AIR Client go through whatever proxy is set up for the machine?  Or is there some special setup you need to do on a per request basis?

Comment: That is what I've read, yes. So the OS/system proxy settings, as defined in IE, have a proxy defined but they do not seem to be picked up by AIR. That's the confusing part. For example, I am checking LAN settings and there is a .dat file set up as 'automatic configuration'. Now that is not defined under 'Proxy server', but it does handle the proxy as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was I was given the wrong URL to access. Once I started using the correct URL then everything worked. The crux of it is that AIR should always pick up proxy settings from default system browser.

Thank you Flextras for your patience.